# Does an enum ALWAYS need to be cast in c# if used as a method parameter?

Tags: c#, javascript, casting, enums

When using an enum as a parameter in a method call, must I cast it to the parameters defined type?

The last 2 lines of code show the exact same method call, except one is cast to an int, the other is not. What should the outcome of these 2 lines be?

Note in my example that the file that includes the enum is a .cs file, the other (poorly written here) is an aspx.cs file. I don’t think it should matter at all, but maybe it does.

Thank you!

```
**fileOne.cs**
[Imported]
public class Foo
{
    [Imported]
    public class Bar
    {
        [Imported]
        [PreserveCase]
        public enum Bam
        {
            [PreserveCase]
            Low = 10,
            [PreserveCase]
            Medium = 50,
            [PreserveCase]
            High = 100
        }
    }
    …code…
    [PreserveCase]
    public static void someMethod(string aString, int aNumber) {}
    …code…
}

**fileTwo.aspx.cs**
…code…

string someStuffForJscript = @”
function afunction(doesntMatter)
{{
    Foo.Bar.someMethod(""This is a string."", (int)Foo.Bar.Bam.Medium);
    Foo.Bar.someMethod(""This is a string."", Foo.Bar.Bam.Medium);
}}
```

*This is oversimplified code, but the concept remains. there are numerous reasons beyond what you see here as to why an enum is used.

Comment: Why not accept the `enum` type in the method? You have to cast it because you're accepting an `int` in the method...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks for the answer.  And to answer your question...in this particular case, all methods described above are legacy code that are used tens of thousands of times in hundreds of files. Not my code to touch, and honestly, there might be a good reason for it.  I just haven't hunted it down.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - In the method call without the cast to (int), there obviously won't be a compile time error because in this case the code is a string.  But what is likely to happen internally?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're asking... ? You're asking why the second one won't fail to compile? ... it will..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Sorry, in simplifying the code, I took out the following in the aspx.cs file: <<private const string someStuffForJscript=@"function afunction()...>>  - In this case it won't compile because it looks like a string to the compiler.  So I imagine in this case, when the line is hit by a user, an error will be thrown internally (and maybe surfaced to the browser or user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using an enum as a parameter in a method call, must I cast it to the parameters defined type?

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

*However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type. For example, the following statement assigns the enumerator Sun to a variable of the type int by using a cast to convert from enum to int.*

```
int x = (int)Days.Sun;
```